# Trouble to get a specific property from an object while no problem with others

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an issue to get a specific property from an object while I can get the other properties.

First of all, I have an array of the object which comes from a Google Spreadsheet.

I use this code to get this array of object:

```
function DataToArrayOfObjects(Url_, SheetName) { //Transforme une G Sheets en Tableau d'objets 
  //Url_ = ""; //Debug
  //SheetName = ""; // Debug
   
  var data = [];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(Url_);
  var spreadsheetId = ss.getId();
  var rangeName = SheetName + '!A1:ZZ';
  var data = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, rangeName).values;
  if (!data) {
    Logger.log('No data found.');
  } else {
  
  var keys = data.shift(),
      i = 0, k = 0,
      obj = null,
      output = [];
  
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    obj = {};
    
    for (k = 0; k < keys.length; k++) {
      obj[keys[k]] = data[i][k];
    }
    
    output.push(obj);
  }
  
  return output;
  }
}
```

The array of the object is [Planning] where each object is as follow {MSN: "Number as string", Start: "Date as string", End: "Date as string", Position: "String" }
I want the properties to be a string when retrieved from G Sheets because the date input format is badly recognized in JavaScript (I rework them to be in "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ" format).

Now the problem is in the code below. In this function, Date_Emprunts is in input and must be between Start/End, and poste must be equal to Position then MSN is returned.

The function has no problem getting values of start, end, and position but MSN is returned as null/undefined...

[image]

But when I look in my array, all the properties are correctly filled:

[image]

I do not have a solution yet.

If someone could bring a new vision, he is welcome :)
Thank you for your interest :D

```
function MSN_finder(Date_Emprunts,poste,Planning){
  //debug
  var Date_Emprunts = "23/07/2020 16:54:20";
  var poste = "P50B";
  var Planning = DataToArrayOfObjects("Sheet_Url","Sheet_Name");
  //
  var emprunt = new Date(Convert_Date_Nexess(Date_Emprunts));
  for (var i=0; i <= Planning.length -1;i++){
    if ( poste == Planning[i].Position ){
      var start = Convert_Date_MSN(Planning[i].Start);
      var end = Convert_Date_MSN(Planning[i].End);
      if (emprunt>start && emprunt<end){
        Logger.log(Planning[i].MSN);
        if(Planning[i].MSN != null){
          return Planning[i].MSN;
        }else{
          return "Non Trouvé";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So, without having the possibillity to access the Spreadsheet I guess you are getting all the keys correctly but for some reason you are not getting the values on the column of ```MSN```. What are you getting when you log your ```data``` object? Are you getting all the values including the ```MSN``` ones?

Comment: Yes, I have all the values. Like here, the log before returning Planning.MSN :
`[20-09-15 10:53:36:492 CEST] { 'MSN': '464',
  PlanningEvent: 'Station-50',
  Position: 'P50B',
  Start: '09/07/2020 6:00',
  End: '24/07/2020 12:00' }`

And I still do not know why ha ha

Edit: You might helped to find something, when I copy/paste the MSN logged in my code, I got a red dot before MSN key.

Comment: After some investigations, the source spreadsheet comes from a CSV that has just changed encoding from a UTF-8 without BOM to a UTF-8 with BOM.
Simply but so vicious

Comment: Solutions should be posted as an answers not as part of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

The spreadsheet comes from a csv file in UTF-8 **with BOM**, the encoding was previously without BOM.

To solve the problem, I used the following code to remove the BOM in the key.

```
//in function DataToArrayOfObjects
...
var data = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, rangeName).values;
if (data[0][0].charCodeAt(0) === 0xFEFF) {
  data[0][0] = data[0][0].substr(1);
}
if(!data){
...
```

Thanks everybody for the help !

Answer (score 1):

From your logs, it would seem that `MSN` key is not present in object.

#### Possible causes:

- Spaces around `MSN`
- Non printable characters like Zero width joiners

Consider debugging like:

```js
const Planning = /*Mock Planning for running snippet here*/[{"Station": "P50", "MSN ": 560}]
const log_ = e => console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
const buggyObject = Planning[0];
const msn = "MSN";
const bKeys = Object.keys(buggyObject);
log_(bKeys);
log_(bKeys.includes(msn));
bKeys.forEach(key => {
  if(key.includes(msn)){
    console.log(`Is this really MSN? ${msn === key}`);
    console.log(`Is length equal? ${msn.length === key.length}`);
    console.log(`Are all characters equal? ${[...key].every((char,i)=>char===msn[i] || console.log(`Something wrong at position ${i}`))}`);
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your help !
Indeed, MSN is not in the object as I want it to be !

The logs : 

`["MSN","PlanningEvent","Position","Start","End"]`
`false`
`Is this really MSN? false`
`Is length equal? false`
`Something wrong at position 0`
`Are all characters equal? false`

I keep searching to solve ! Haha

Comment: @BretonGaëtan Position 0 means first character is not equal.

Comment: Yes, it seems I have a non printable characters, like you suggested...
I have a red dot before MSN in the key name when I copy/paste the key from the logger

Comment: After some investigations, the source spreadsheet comes from a CSV that has just changed encoding from a UTF-8 without BOM to a UTF-8 with BOM.
Simply but so vicious

Comment: @BretonGaëtan So fixed?

Comment: Yes ! Problem fixed !